# Linq to SQL, Update a lot of Data before One Insert

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, triggers

Before insert new value to table, I need change one field in all rows of that table.
What the best way to do this? in c# code, ore use trigger? if C# can you show me the code?

**UPD**
**NEW VERSION of Question** 
Hello. Before insert new value to table, I need change one field in all rows of that table with specific ID( It is FK to another table).
What the best way to do this? in c# code, ore use trigger? if C# can you show me the code?

Comment: In any case trigger will work faster than linq to sql, because LINQ doesn't allow to change a lot of data by single request

Answer (score 2):

You should probably consider changing your design this doesn't sound like it will scale well, i would probably do it with a trigger if it is always required, but if not, id use `ExecuteCommand`.

```
var ctx = new MyDataContext();
ctx.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE myTable SET foo = 'bar'");
```

Comment: suppose I have versions of my items. If I make update to my item I will save new version. I need to know what item was last. For this reason only one row should have value.

Comment: +1 in particular for noting the scaling issues; that poor innocent transaction log! And unsuspecting diff-backup.

Comment: @Sergii ah, a temporal database... There are several approaches to that, but even so that isn't quite an "all rows" update - it is just a "single last-active row for this item" update... One updated row per revision insert. It can also be done in an append-only way, but finding "active" is more expensive then. Another approach is a SEPARATE audit table, so transactional is active-only

Comment: ok. In that table will save other versions for other items. Ok not all rows. Rows with specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment on Paul's answer, I feel like I should chime in here. We have a few tables where we need to keep a history of each entry in that table. We implement this by creating a separate table for each. For example, we may have a `Comment` table, and then a `CommentArchive` table with a foreign key reference to the `CommentId` in the `Comment` table.

A trigger on the `Comment` table ensures that each time certain fields in the `Comment` table are updated, the "old" version (which is accessible via the `deleted` table in the trigger) gets pushed to the `CommentArchive` table. Obviously, this means several `CommentArchive` entries may exist for each `Comment`, but if you're only looking for the "active" comments, you just look in the `Comment` table. And if you need information about the history of a comment, you can easily use LINQ to SQL to jump from the Comment you're interested in to the CommentArchives that reference it.

Because the triggers we use in the above example only insert a single value into the Archive table for each update, they run very quickly and we get good performance. We had issues recently where I tried making the triggers more complex and we started getting dead-locks with as few as 15 concurrent transactions. So the lesson is that you should make these triggers simple, and make them touch as few rows in as few tables as possible.